# Способен ли ESLint полностью заменить Prettier?

Tags: eslint, prettier

Часто мне приходится видеть **eslintrc** и **prettierrc** в одном проекте, при этом по крайней мере большинство правил из **prettierrc** покрываются ESLint. Можно ли заявить "Prettier совершенно не нужен, так он полностью дублирует функционал более мощного ESLint"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Мнение основанное на документации

Это два разных инструмента, которые выполняют каждый свою задачу.

ESlint - инструмент для статического анализа кода. То есть анализ без реального исполнения исследуемых программ. Данный инструмент охватывает вопросы качества кода и стиля программирования.

Prettier - это инструмент для форматирования кода.

Оба эти инструменты используются вместе. Точно сказать, что один нужен, а другой нет, нельзя. Здесь скорей зависит от правил принятых командой разработчиков и используемых в реальных проектах.

Также в [документации Prettier](https://prettier.io/docs/en/comparison.html) можно найти их сравнение. Можно обратить внимание на последнее заключение

> In other words, use Prettier for formatting and linters for catching bugs!

> Другими словами, используй Prettier для форматирование и линтеры для ловли багов